# How to handle difference in the naming convention of request body JSON fields produced in javascript and consumed in python DRF?

Tags: python, angularjs, rest, django-rest-framework, naming-conventions

I am creating Rest APIs in Python DRF and consuming it in angularJS in the browser. The problem I am facing is wrt, differences in variable name naming conventions in javascript and python.

Javascript uses camel notation to name variable names, while python uses underscore notation.

So, when I send request through angularjs, the sample request JSON body is of following format :-

```
user_dtls = {"firstName": "Mangu Singh", "lastName": "Rajpurohit"}
```

but in python, they are represented as `first_name` and `last_name`.
I am using `ModelSerializer`, while automatically reads the request and populates model fields, based on field_name.

But, since the names of fields in request body(send through javascript) and serializer is different, I have to write lot of boilerplate code to do this conversion.

Do DRF provides any mechanism to handle this situation ? What would be the most pythonic way to deal with such situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `source` option in the serializer. Using that you can rename model serializer fields by overriding them. For example

```
class UserSerializer(serializer.ModelsSerializer):
    firstName = serializer.CharField(source="first_name", max_length=100)
    lastName = serializer.CharField(source="last_name", max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('firstName', 'lastName')
```